# Help reading this please

Tags: meaning

[image]This is from a kanken game. Theres quite a few I cant read. Is it okay to post more as I find them to ask for help? Of course I will try google first.

Comment: The image appears very clear to me. If by "can't read" you mean "can't understand the meaning", please explain more clearly what you mean. Note that unfocused translation requests are generally considered off-topic, so any update to the question should be about some specific part of the text. And if you tried google, explain what you found.

Comment: Since he's saying it's a Kanken game, by "there's quite a few I can't read" I am guessing he means kanji, which is something one can easily look up in a dictionary.

Comment: Okay, when I type "dai o tsukatte takai tokoro no mono o totta" in google it translates it as, "I took a high place with a big use." Which to me makes zero sense. That is why I asked for help translating it. Am i not allowed to ask what a sentence means? I have to ask only individual words?

Comment: Yes, merely asking for a translation is off-topic here. Please refer to the help section for guidelines on questions. It need not be about a single word, but it should be a focused question on some aspect you are struggling with.

Comment: To be fair, I read the help section and dont see anywhere that it says not to ask for the translation of a sentence. All of the sentences are very short. It does say not to be open ended but a translation is very specific. I guess I need to just post half of the sentence or something. I dont understand what Im allowed or not. Do you know of another site that would help with sentences I cant understand in the case I cant translate it myself with google?

Comment: If your question contained information about what you do and don't understand about the sentence that would be focused."I don't understand" by itself is unfocused. Think of it this way, there are thousands of levels this sentence could be explained from. We want to help you reach a better understanding not just say what the translation is.

Comment: Google Translate may not be the best tool for your purpose. You can convert the katakana part into hiragana and look it up in any online bilingual dictionary. You may get multiple entries. Find the one whose meaning seems to fit in the sentence best. The kanji should be listed there, too.

Comment: I see now what you are saying. Okay, I will do better in explaining what I do know and dont know and what exactly isnt making sense. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3):

ダイ（台）is a small stool/step ladder that you stand on to reach things high up.

つかって（使う）means to use.

とった（取る）means to take.

So the sentence means:

(They/She/He/I) used a stool to take something from a high place (for example a high shelf).

Comment: Thank you for this. When I looked up the kanji for Dai it gave me multiple meanings such as stand, rack, table, support, belt, coubter for machines, setting for jewelry, level, range, period of time, etc.